# Getting runtime error for input dimension mismatch for inceptionV3

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I changed the dimension many way. But not a single change work for me. Here is my code

```
#transform for inceptionV3  


train_transform = transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.Resize((299, 299)),
                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                    transforms.ToTensor(), 
                    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

val_transform = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize((299, 299)),
                transforms.ToTensor(), 
                transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
vocab = dataloader.get_vocab(dataset=args.dataset)()
# Data loader and validation split
#num_workers will be 4, I have used 0 for chittron
data_loader = dataloader.get_data_loader(dataset=args.dataset)(mode="train",
                                                               transform=train_transform,
                                                               vocab=vocab,
                                                               batch_size=args.batch_size,
                                                               shuffle=True,
                                                               num_workers=4, 
                                                               data_dir=args.data_dir)

valid_data_loader = dataloader.get_data_loader(dataset=args.dataset)(mode="val",
                                                                    transform=val_transform,
                                                                     vocab=vocab,
                                                                 batch_size=args.batch_size,
                                                                     shuffle=False,
                                                                     num_workers=4, 
                                                                     data_dir=args.data_dir)
```

And the main code is:

```
inception_v3 = getattr(models, dictionary['cnn_model'])(pretrained=True)
 # remove the last fc layer
self.inception_v3 = nn.Sequential(*list(inception_v3.children())[:-1])

for param in self.inception_v3.parameters():
     param.requires_grad = False
self.encoder_linear = nn.Linear(inception_v3.fc.in_features, dictionary['embed_size'])
self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(dictionary['embed_size'])

self.embedding = nn.Embedding(dictionary['vocab_size'], dictionary['embed_size'])
self.rnn = getattr(nn, dictionary['rnn_model'])(dictionary['embed_size'], dictionary['hidden_size'], dictionary['num_layers'], batch_first=True)
self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dictionary['dropout'])
self.decoder_linear = nn.Linear(dictionary['hidden_size'], dictionary['vocab_size'])

self.init_weights()
```

And i am getting this error.

> self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups) RuntimeError: Expected
> 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 192 768 1 1, but got
> 2-dimensional input of size [8, 1000] instead

Any idea what should do. Is my code okay?

Comment: Error is due to the mismatch between the input layer of the model and the shape of the data.

Comment: What data are you using? I am assuming images since you are using Inception model but your error says its a Tensor of Rank 2.

Comment: @yuRa Yes, I am using flickr8k dataset. I am already use for ResNet and Vgg16, they work perfectly. But inception doesn't work for me.